# TFS 2010 configure Gated Check-in to save test results into the drop folder

Tags: tfs, automated-tests, build-process

I am attempting to configure the "Gated Check-in" feature for our main trunk. I've got it configured to build to a drop folder `\\server\BuildOutput`.

On each build I am getting the "Debug", "Release", and "logs" folders as I expected from my build definition.

**My issue is as follows:** I would like to get the test results (.TRX files from the build agent) from each build and put them in a "TestResults" folder. I can't seem to find where to configure this option. I've tried setting the "TestResultsDirectory" variable in the "Run On Agent" section of the build process template to `BuildDetail.DropLocation + "\TestResults"` with no luck.

Am I looking in the wrong location? or where should I look to set this up.

Comment: I don't believe that test results are meant to be copied to the drop location - they are meant to be published. Are you able to access the test results through the build log?

Comment: @John Saunders Thank you for your reply .... yes I can get to them through the build log, the problem is that the build agent overwrites the test results on each run. My goal was to save the test results for each run.

Comment: They _are_ saved. Try to access the results from two builds ago and find out.

Comment: @John Saunders Thank you ! I'll dig into the API and attempt to get the results from past Gated Builds.

Comment: @John Saunders - Correct, the test results are saved in past builds.  However, any output the tests produce (i.e. a screenshot during headless testing) which is saved to the Out folder of the test run in the test results folder are not saved.  Not sure if Scott Vercuski is looking to save the contents of the Out folder.